# How to mark a line in datagrid (Windows Mobile)?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

How I can run any query, and to marker the first line that I found in
Datagrid?

I work on [Windows Mobile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Mobile), .NET FrameWork 3.5.

Comment: You'll have to give us a little bit more information of what you want to achieve. What do you mean by marker? Highlight a row? Check a Checkbox in a row?

Answer (score 0):

For #1, take a look at Ilya Tumanov's [example of custom formatting data in the DataGrid](http://blogs.msdn.com/netcfteam/archive/2006/04/25/583542.aspx). He does custom painting of cells in it, which is how you would achieve highlighting.